# how to delete unwanted (padding) columns from a square gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to build a square from a grid view (width = height) 
I achieved that by using Layout Pa rams, but I got some wired padding columns (the gray ones)

grid view screenshot:

[image]

I would like to delete (or make very small that no one can notice)

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pading_board2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pading_board2"

    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

    android:background="@drawable/porcarie2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:numColumns="9"
    android:padding="@dimen/pading_board"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp"

    android:columnWidth="80dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"


    />
```

code

```
if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, parent, false);`


child.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75,75));
```

cell XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cellRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/centralNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="9"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/possibilitiesTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:ems="7"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/possibilitiesBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="12345"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

central number
possibilities Top
possibilities Bottom

Comment: Use a table layout and set padding 0

Comment: Have you tried setting your vertical and horizontal spacing equal to 0?

Comment: yes I tried changing vertical and horizontal spacing to 0, however its the black lines which I need it to stay there @Jantzilla

Comment: post your `cell_layout.xml`

Comment: @sneharc I updated my question with my cell xml code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cell_layout.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cellRoot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/possibilitiesTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="12345"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centralNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/possibilitiesBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="12345"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately I already tried it and It doesn't help @sneharc

Comment: Try removing `child.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75,75));` , `android:columnWidth="80dp"` and other width height padding margin wherever you have applied and see. Then add them one by one to check which of them is causing the problem.

Comment: I actually added them only after in order to make squares so I'm afraid it doesn't the solution to my problem @sneharc